# Can google index your site menu with .load()?

Tags: jquery, html, web-crawler

I've been told google can't index a site's menu structure I worked on.  I'm loading the menu from a master template through .load() and I'm wondering if that's the issue?

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $('header').load('/master-header.html');
   });
</script>
```

Comment: I think search engines don't index dynamic things. But why don't just insert that HTML into your HTML? If you're just trying to avoid repeating/copying your header in several files, have a look at [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/) (or any other static site generator), your life will change forever.

Comment: ya, that's what i was trying to avoid without a CMS to just do an "embed" without .load()

Comment: If you're working with backend scripting like php on this site, you can dynamically load the content on the server side that way the the html is already present when the page loads